# How to mount directory with mount point that contains non ascii characters on Mac 10.10?

Tags: macos, nfs, finder, sshfs, cfstring

I want to mount directory, from Ubuntu to Mac, with mount point that contains non ASCII characters, for example:

```
/User/user/zdjęcia
```

Whole process is finished successfully and this directory is visible both from command prompt and when I call 'df' - mount point has proper path. However, I am not able to open it in explorer. When I open system logs to see what happens I see that my path is converted to:

```
/Users/user/zdjƒôcia
```

When I use regular paths, it works. I already tried to use NFC normalization and also change string coding. I am using SSHFS. Has anyone already met this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to connect properly. I am able to see every file in the explorer. It appeared that normalizations NFD and NFKD work. There is a new problem now. I am not able to open files that contain non ASCII.